# Finding a square on four lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry

There are four lines A, B, C, D in 3D space, they all go through (0,0,0). There is a point Ma on a line A.

I need to find points Mb, Mc, Md on lines B, C, D, such that Ma, Mb, Mc, Md forms a square in space (equal edge lengths, right angles ...). We expect that such square exists.

Is there an explicit solution? Can it be computed with an iterative algorithm?

Comment: As I said, I expect the solution exists. Imagine you draw  a square on the floor, glue strings to its corners and pull the strings into one point in the room.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\vec a=M_a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c$, $\vec d$ be four vectors giving the directions of lines $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. We must find three numbers $r$, $s$, $t$ such that $M_b=r\vec b$, $M_c=s\vec c$, $M_d=t\vec d$ and $M_aM_bM_cM_d$ is a square.

A square is (1) a parallelogram with (2) equal sides and (3) right angles. Condition (1) is satisfied if and only if diagonals $M_aM_c$ and $M_bM_d$ have the same midpoint, that is if and only if:
$$
\tag{1}
r\vec b + t\vec d - s\vec c = \vec a.
$$
We can get rid of two terms on the LHS by taking the scalar product of both sides with $\vec b\times\vec d$ or $\vec b\times\vec c$ or $\vec c\times\vec d$. We can then solve for the remaining unknown:
$$
s=-{(\vec b\times\vec d)\cdot\vec a\over(\vec b\times\vec d)\cdot\vec c},\quad
r={(\vec c\times\vec d)\cdot\vec a\over(\vec c\times\vec d)\cdot\vec b},\quad
t={(\vec b\times\vec c)\cdot\vec a\over(\vec b\times\vec c)\cdot\vec d}.
$$
Note that all denominators give the same result (sign apart), for the [circular shift property of scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Properties), and do not vanish if lines $B$, $C$, $D$ are not coplanar (the case when all lines lie in the same plane requires a different solution, see edit below).
Hence you can always find a parallelogram but of course there is no guarantee it is also a square, if you take four generic lines. On the other hand the solution is unique, hence if you know it was a square you'll obtain that.

EDIT.

In the case all lines lie in the same plane, then equation $(1)$ is equivalent to 2 scalar equations and its solution gives the values for only two unknowns, for instance $r$ and $t$. We can solve it by the same technique used above, taking the vector product of both sides with $\vec b$ or $\vec d$. We obtain:
$$
r={(\vec d\times\vec a)+s(\vec d\times\vec c)
\over(\vec d\times\vec b)},\quad
t={(\vec b\times\vec a)+s(\vec b\times\vec c)
\over(\vec b\times\vec d)}.
$$
Parameter $s$ is then available to enforce one of the other conditions, for instance $(r\vec b-\vec a)\cdot(t\vec d-\vec a)=0$ to obtain a rectangle.